# I'm having trouble using ggplot2 to reproduce a violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data includes a combination of mutations for several genes per sample, the counts, and the MIC (these are discrete) for the antibiotic the bacteria was screened on.

Here is toy data:

```
structure(list(count = c(4L, 26L, 96L, 93L, 2L, 22L), combo = structure(c(22L, 
19L, 2L, 2L, 20L, 19L), .Label = c("HFALSEAIVTANGGAL", "HFALSEAIVTANGGAP", 
"HFALSEAIVTANGGTP", "HFALSEAIVTANSGAP", "HFALSEAIVTAYGGTP", "HFALSEAIVTTNSGAP", 
"HFALSEAIVTVNGGAL", "HFALSEAIVTVNGGAS", "HFALSEAIVTVNSGAP", "HFALSEAMTTAYGSAA", 
"HFALSEAMTTAYGSAP", "HFALSEAMTTAYGSTP", "HTRUEAIVSANGGAP", "HTRUEAIVTANGGAP", 
"HTRUEAIVTANSGAP", "HTRUEAIVTTNSGAP", "HTRUEAMTTAYGSAP", "YFALSEAIVTANGGAL", 
"YFALSEAIVTANGGAP", "YFALSEAIVTANGGAS", "YFALSEAIVTANSGAP", "YFALSEAIVTTNGGAL", 
"YFALSEAIVTTNGGAP", "YFALSEAIVTTNSGAP", "YFALSEAIVTVNGGAL", "YFALSEAMTTANGGAP", 
"YFALSEAMTTANGGTP", "YFALSEAMTTAYGSAA", "YFALSEAMTTAYGSAP", "YFALSEAMTTAYGSAS", 
"YFALSEAMTTAYGSTP", "YFALSENFNFNFNFNFNFNFNFNFNF", "YTRUEAIVTANGGAL", 
"YTRUEAIVTANGGAP", "YTRUEAMTTAYGSAP"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This goes on and on for each MIC category (there are 8 on a log2 scale).

I am attempting to create a violin plot like this (source: https://www.thelancet.com/journals/laninf/article/PIIS1473-3099(18)30225-1/fulltext
):
[image]

I attempted to write some code but didn't get very far:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(combo), y=mic)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width=.01, outlier.size=0, fill="grey50") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", fill="white", shape=21, size=4)
p
```

Here is what that plot looks like: 
[image]

I can easily create a count table but I was hoping to have some visual like the image produced below. Can someone steer me in the right direction?

[image]

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = combo, y=mic)) 
p + geom_violin()  + geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.1, aes(color=factor(combo)))
```

Comment: The example graphs you show use a log scale for the y-axis. Try adding `+ scale_y_continuous(trans = "log")` to your plot.

Comment: @Gregor It appears that exponentiated the MIC values but the overall figure didn't change.

Comment: If that didn't work, instead of sharing a picture of your data, could you share a small sample of your data in a copy/pasteable format (`dput()` is best) so that we can try solutions ourselves before suggesting them?

Comment: Added the dput() as suggested.

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html to add the points try experimenting with: `p + geom_violin() + geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.1, aes(color=factor(combo)))` .

Comment: Can you be more specific about which characteristic(s) of the other graph you'd like to reproduce?  (Is it the colors?  The dashed lines?  The facets?  The additional points under the x-axis?)

Comment: the additional points under the x-axis might be simple geom_point() or geom_count(), then arranged with a library like cowplot.   

nycflights13::flights%>%
  group_by(dest) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(dest)) %>% 
  filter(rank <= 15)%>% select(origin, dest)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=origin, y=dest, color=origin))+theme_minimal()+
  geom_point(size=10) #or #geom_count()

Comment: I can't reproduce your plotting code because your toy data doesn't have a column named `mic`

Comment: I added my latest attempt but still cannot figure out how to get the x-axis like in the published figure.

Comment: @A.S.K. Really it's the actual graph itself and the additional points under the x-axis. I can't say I've ever seen that before. I've seen some examples of the dashed lines and colors so I think I'm okay there.

Comment: Please consider that most publication-graphs are edited (sometimes heavily) in specialized applications, and that most plotting-workhorses like `ggplot` and `lattice` will get you close, but rarely there

Comment: @user3105519: maybe this can help? https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/33/18/2938/3884387

Comment: I would just like to point out that the plots in the Lancet article are `upset` plots (a modern derivative of Venn diagrams) and not violin plots, despite the legend of the Lancet figure referring to them as violin plots.  I see you have actually attempted to make violin plots, but you should probably be using `UpsetR` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your plotting code, as it lacks the column `mic`. However, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
# load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

# make toy data
set.seed(1); a <- data.frame(kind = sample(letters[1:10], 500, TRUE), value = sample(1:20, 500, TRUE))

# plot
ggplot(a, aes(x = kind, y = value, colour = kind))+geom_violin()+geom_sina(size = 2.1)
```

Of course you can play with the format (the shize of the points in the `geom_sina` call is the most evident).

[image]

### EDIT

```
# redefine the first plot, removing the legend:
p1 <- ggplot(a, aes(x = kind, y = value, colour = kind))+
  geom_violin()+
  geom_sina(size = 1.1)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Define toy data for the lower plot:
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
Genes <- data.table(gene = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 20, TRUE), 
                    n = sample(1:10, 20, TRUE))

# add a coloring variable
Genes[, coloring := cut(n, 3, labels = 1:3)]

# plot the lower plot
p2 <- ggplot(Genes, aes(n, gene, colour = coloring))+
  geom_point(size = 2.8)+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none", 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank())

# put both plots in the canvas:
library(patchwork)
p1+
 p2+
 plot_layout(ncol = 1, heights = c(.8, .2))
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: what do you need with the x axis?

Comment: I can see there are some names (genes, I suppose) in the y axis. The dots seem to represent the presence, absence of something, but what is that variable?

Comment: I'm struggling trying to figure out how to code the presence or absence of the genes. It appears that each gene on the X-axis is represented by one color, which matches the violin plots, plotted against the Y-axis MIC values.  If I make my X-axis the combination of Genes (say: ABDFJ) then that is colored by one color, but it wont match the lower plot. @PavoDive

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to me that your biggest problem is that you don't fully understand the plot you're trying to emulate, and therefore it is very difficult to know for sure what is missing. Once you're sure about what you need, please advice. I'll be happy to help

Comment: I need the bottom list of genes in the Article figure to match the color of the violin plots in the main figure. In the article figure the x-axis appears to be a combination of mutations. However the lower plot does not show the combination of mutations, rather it breaks that combination into individual gene mutations. Unless there is a way to plot each gene mutation on the X-axis? Thanks for your help @PavoDive

Comment: *"In the article figure the x-axis appears to be"* confirms my suspicion. Once you fully understand the plot in the article, **and whether if your data is enough to produce it**, you'll be able to state better your needs and we'll be able to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195706/discussion-between-user3105519-and-pavodive).

Comment: I've figured this out and created a data frame that has presence and absence of mutations, and the combination of mutations. I am satifisfied with the upper portion of the graph and would now like to work on the bottom portion. I am not all that familiar with data.table. I usually just import my data as a .csv file. Would you be able to show me how I can generate the subplot using that data? The structure is the same as your "Gene" table. I am just unfamiliar with how you would use it with real data imported into R. Thanks! @PavoDive

Comment: If the structure is just the same as `Gene`, why don't you plot it using the code provided and mark the answer as accepted? If you aren't able to do it, please consider asking a new question showing your data, what you have attempted and the problems you have faced

Answer (score 1):

A long time has passed, and now there is an `R` package called `ggupset` which makes charts similar to those linked in The Lancet.

https://github.com/const-ae/ggupset

> Plot a combination matrix instead of the standard x-axis and create **UpSet plots** with ggplot2.

[image: ggupset example violin plot from github]